# How to detect moving speed of device when recording video in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i am developing an camera application and i want to warn user when they move their device very fast while recording with camera.

so i want to detect moving speed of device (left to right) and warn user that device is moving so fast

is ios have any simple method to detect speed movement of device?

Please help

Comment: have u tried using UIAccelerometerDelegate and opting for `didAccelerate` method and observing change in the value of acceleration of the device and then adding the cap on that value and decide when to warn ur user

Comment: @Hardik have you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Use Shake Gesture

override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}   


override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {

       // Your Code or Show Alert
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer seems good (I'm not an iOS developer) but it could be improved with a bit of explanatory text.